# Visual Studio doesn't see code changes at runtime

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I recently noticed a strange behavior on Visual Studio (2022, enterprise): whenever I make code changes, I can't see those changes during runtime unless I do a clean + build of the solution.
This started to happen only in the last few days, and I can't understand why (previously, for the specific application on which I'm working on, I just had to do a solution build before running).

It's not the end of the world, but my work is quite slown down having to do a solution clean  every time.

P.s. I already tried to delete both the bin and obj folders for every "inner" project inside the solution, but it didn't help.

Comment: Sometimes restarting Visual Studio or your computer is the only way to make weird stuff like this stop happening. (Turn it off and on again)

Comment: More than likely, the binary you are debugging didn't actually get rebuilt. If you can repro the problem just using msbuild from the commandline, you can add a /bl switch to generate a .binlog, and use the structured log viewer to try and diagnose why the binary isn't being update. structured log viewer can be downloaded from https://msbuildlog.com. There is a "Project System Tools" extension in the VS marketplace, that also facilitates capturing .binlog's for builds in the IDE. When you open the .binlog you'll see that any tasks or targets that were skipped are grayed out.